# Filtered Stream with any match on two objects set a value of one object to the value of another object

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

Long time reader/ lurker in the shadows, first time poster.
Might be a bit of a silly question and I am sure there is an easy solution.

What I have is a List of Customers and a List of Suppliers

Customers:

```java
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    private String supplerName;
```

Suppliers

```java
    private int ID;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private int customerID;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

I am fetching some dummy info with:

```java
List<Supplier> suppliersList = supplierRepository.findAll();
List<Customer> customersList = customerRepository.findAll();
```

Which is returning me something like this:

```
Suppliers List:
==============================================================================================
  Supplier{ID=1, name='Supplier A', age=19, customerID=1, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.798}
, Supplier{ID=2, name='Supplier B', age=20, customerID=1, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.799}
, Supplier{ID=3, name='Supplier C', age=21, customerID=2, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.799}
, Supplier{ID=4, name='Supplier D', age=22, customerID=3, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.799}
==============================================================================================
Customers List:
  Customer{ID=1, name='Customer A', age=19, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.770}
, Customer{ID=2, name='Customer B', age=20, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.779}
, Customer{ID=3, name='Customer C', age=21, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.779}
, Customer{ID=4, name='Customer D', age=22, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:15:31.779}
==============================================================================================
```

Basically what I want to do is if the customerID in Suppliers matches the ID in customer I want to set the supplierName in customers to the name value from Suppliers.

I already have a stream that is finding me the matches

```java
List<Customer> filteredList = customersList.stream()
                .filter(cust -> suppliersList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(supl -> String.valueOf(cust.getID())
                                .equals(String.valueOf(supl.getCustomerID())))
                ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which gives me the following output for the 3 matched ID's

```
  Customer{ID=1, name='Customer A', age=19, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:22:16.768}
, Customer{ID=2, name='Customer B', age=20, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:22:16.776}
, Customer{ID=3, name='Customer C', age=21, createdDate=2020-09-25T23:22:16.777}
```

So long story short what I am trying to achieve is for all these matches I want to set the Customer supplierName to the name value in Supplier.

At some point I would also like to also join another stream of objects (so we would now have 3 streams) and set one or multiple values from one object to another. Bonus points if anyone has a solution for that :)

Comment: It's better to fetch merged data directly from the database depends on relations.

Comment: Still, if you want a solution after fetching, you can create a map of customerId-supplierName iterating supplier list and iterate the customer list and set the supplierName getting from map- O(n).

Comment: From your example, I see that you might have many suppliers for one customer. What happens in this case? Which supplier name should be set to the customer?

Comment: Hi  Eklavya, yeah ideally I would like to do it after fetching. What I am looking at doing, is there is a really inefficient query which joins a large amount of tables, into a massive object. I would like to split this into multiple smaller queries joining less tables into smaller objects and then combine those objects into one. So if to start off with I could work out what to do in the customers and suppliers example I am hoping I could apply the same sort of thing to the large query.

Comment: Hi fps, good question. I should probably look at refining the example. For the solution we can safely assume there will be a one to one mapping. possibly multiple ids in the second set (suppliers) like in the example but would be highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this task is better done without a pure stream solution. Here it is, separated in steps:

```
Map<Integer, List<Supplier>> suppliersByCustomerId = suppliersList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Supplier::getCustomerID));
```

This groups suppliers by customerID. Then, we need to iterate the customers and check if there are suppliers for each one of them. If there's a match, we set the name of the first supplier to the customer.

```
customers.forEach(c -> {
    List<Supplier> suppliers = suppliersByCustomerId.get(c.getID());
    if (suppliers != null && !suppliers.isEmpty()) {
        Supplier first = suppliers.get(0);
        String suppliername = first.getName();
        c.setSupplierName(supplierName);
    }
});
```

As you are not specifying what to do if there are many suppliers per customer, I've decided to set the name of the first supplier to the customer.

Comment: Hi fps, that works like a charm, and agreed it does makes a lot more sense to split it out. I am still quite new to streams so far they have being quite confusing and I still have a lot to learn.

This will also be alot easier for me to implement with multiple streams and object lists. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You can collect directly first name as map key like `...collect(Collectors.toMap(Supplier::getCustomerID, Supplier::getName, (a, b) -> a))`

Comment: cool thanks Eklavya, will have a look into that as well